# WPF Mediaelement freezes while repeating position property for fastforward

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls, mediaelement

Requirement is to create a fast forward button which will forward the video continuously. I am using the position property by adding timespan while doing fast-forward of video. While forwarding manually(click by click), for each button click, it executes ones and media moves by timespan amt. The problem is if I click the fast forward button multiple times (around 10 times), the media freezes. There is also a seek bar that continues to progresses without issue. However the media element freezes.

XAML

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Mediaelement" LoadedBehavior="Manual" ScrubbingEnabled="True"  MediaOpened="MediaOpened" UnloadedBehavior="Manual" Source="{Binding MediaFile}"/>
```

Code in View Model

```
private void  FastForward() 
    {
          Mediaelement.Position += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);        
    }
```

I also tried mimicking continuous forward using the below code. But this is also resulting in frame freeze after few(~10) frame moves

Code:

```
private async void  FastForward()
    {
        do
        {      
        Mediaelement.Position += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        await Task.Delay(1000);   
        } while (MediaelementPosition < Mediaelement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan);   
    }
```

I do use a DispatcherTimer and TimerTick to synchronize seeker/progress bar with the media element. That is working fine but not sure if that has to any effect in frame freeze.

Frame is not freezing at the end or at the beginning. It's happening in the middle where the next frame supposed to show up. I have also play and pause functionalities which are working as expected.
Any suggestion/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I never worked with that control. Is the media playing while you aim to fast-forward? Is the media resource a local file or a remote URI?
Maybe you have to await buffering being finished before proceeding to the next position

Comment: I tried with local file as well as remote file. Same issue in both. Will try adding await buffering.